# Java Swing Borders to textfields and buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing UI which contains 6 text fields and labels for the input and 1 button and texfield to show the output. now I want to make a border around these two.

I have read some materials regarding Titled borders but I think its only for single elements. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a JPanel with a titled border, then put however many components you wanted in the JPanel using the content manager of your choice.

An example:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "My Title", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));

myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

JButton button = new JButton("New button");
myPanel.add(button);

JLabel label = new JLabel("New label");
myPanel.add(label);
```

Comment: Just to clarify all of TitledBorder's parameters:

Comment: public TitledBorder(Border border,
                    String title,
                    int titleJustification,
                    int titlePosition,
                    Font titleFont,
                    Color titleColor)

Comment: Please check your code snippet, I think you have a typo of some sort. I guess you should either change myPanel to panel or the other way around. :)

Comment: @Boro Thanks for that, edited all instances of "panel" to "myPanel".

Answer (score 3):

You can add that last 2 components to a JPanel and then add that panel to main frame. Now you can give border to JPanel and it will around 2 components inside it.

To give border to jPanel you can use following:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

---

If you want titled border then you can use following:

```
pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
            .createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, Color.blue), "Title",
            TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP));
```

Reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: +1 but since he seems to want titled border, maybe you should change it to use `BorderFactory.createTitledBorder`

Comment: I found out that now we have the same rep. maybe I should remove this upvote? ;)

Comment: @MByD: do what you feel. I'm not gonna charge for it.